# One scaler for all features or one scaler per feature?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-cleaning, preprocessing, feature-scaling

I have a time series with more than 30 features. For preprocessing with scikit learn do you usually use one scaler per feature or one scaler for all features that should be standardized/normalized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sklearn scaler works on feature/column** *(and thats why you want)*

Imagine if it did not. Than you would shift your mean and std in weird-determined-by distribution-of-the-whole-set-kind of way.